# CUDA/C matrix multiplication

Tags: c, cuda, matrix-multiplication

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying create a program that returns a matrix to a power using cuda.
It seems as if cudaMemcpy (ln103) doesnt return the result array. I check it by returning the first element in the matrix but I always just get 0. Maybe theres something wrong with my kernel? Would appreciate any help:

EDIT: I should clarify, the kernel is iterated (starting with the matrix multiplied by the respective identity matrix, then multiplied by every result thereafter) until k times which gives the matrix to the power.

i.e. A is a matrix 
A^0 = I (identity matrix)
A^k = A^(k-1)*A

input :

```
<n>
<power>
<element>
.....
```

code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define BLOCK 8
#define SIZE (BLOCK * 64)
#define TILE_SIZE (8)

int n;


float *
create_matrix_h(unsigned int w, unsigned int h) {
  float *m;
  m = (float *) malloc(w * h * sizeof(float));
  if (m == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to malloc.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return m;
}

__global__ void
kernel3(const float *m1, const float *m2, float *m3, unsigned int width) {
  const unsigned int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  const unsigned int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int t, i;
  float result = 0, a, b;

  for (t = 0; t < width / TILE_SIZE; ++t) {
    for (i = 0; i != TILE_SIZE; ++i) {
      a = m1[row*width + t*TILE_SIZE + i];
      b = m2[(t*TILE_SIZE + i)*width + col];
      result += a * b;
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  m3[row*width + col] = result;
}

float *
create_matrix_d(int w, int h) {
  float *m;
  if (cudaMalloc(&m, w * h * sizeof(float)) == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to cudaMalloc.\n");
    return NULL;
    //exit(1);
  }
  return m;
}

void
fill_matrix_h(float *const m, int w, int h, float *const values, int nvalues) {
  int i, j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i != w * h; ++i) {
    m[i] = values[j];
    j = (j + 1) % nvalues;
  }
}

int
main(void) {
    int k;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) !=1 || n<1){
        return 0;
    }
    if (scanf(" %d", &k) !=1 || k<0){
        return 0;
    }
    float *hm[3], *dm[3];
    dim3 bdim(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    dim3 gdim(SIZE/TILE_SIZE, SIZE/TILE_SIZE);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        hm[i] = create_matrix_h(SIZE, SIZE);
        dm[i] = create_matrix_d(SIZE, SIZE);
    }
    float tem[n*n];
    for(i=0; i<n*n; ++i) {
        if (scanf(" %f", &tem[i]) !=1){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    float temid[n*n];
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i != n*n; ++i) {
        if (i==0 || i == j + (n+1)) {
            temid[i] = 1;
            j = i;
        }
        else {
            temid[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    fill_matrix_h(hm[0], SIZE, SIZE, tem, sizeof(tem)/sizeof(float));
    fill_matrix_h(hm[1], SIZE, SIZE, temid, sizeof(temid)/sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dm[0], hm[0], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int w;
    for (w=0; w<k; ++w) {
        cudaMemcpy(dm[1], hm[1], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        kernel3<<<gdim, bdim>>>(dm[0], dm[1], dm[2], SIZE);
            cudaThreadSynchronize();
        cudaMemcpy(hm[2], dm[2], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        hm[1] = hm[2];
    }
    printf(" %.3f ", hm[2][0]);
    return 0;

 }
```

thanks for your reply pavan. Now when I run it i get an infinite loop with the below input at the kernel call. Also new code. I appreciate your help

```
 2
 2
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

new code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define BLOCK 8
#define SIZE (BLOCK * 64)
#define TILE_SIZE (8)

int n;


float *
create_matrix_h(unsigned int w, unsigned int h) {
  float *m;
  m = (float *) malloc(w * h * sizeof(float));
  if (m == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to malloc.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return m;
}

void
print_matrix(const float *m, const int w, const int h) {
  int x, y;
  for (y = 0; y != h; ++y) {
    for (x = 0; x != w; ++x)
      printf("%.03f ", m[y*w + x]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}


void
cpu_mult(const float *m1, const float *m2, float *m3, unsigned int width) {
  unsigned int i, j, k;
  float result;

  for (i = 0; i != width; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j != width; ++j) {
      result = 0;
      for (k = 0; k != width; ++k)
        result += m1[i*width + k] * m2[k*width + j];
      m3[i*width + j] = result;
    }
  }
}


__global__ void
kernel3(const float *m1, const float *m2, float *m3, unsigned int width) {
  const unsigned int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  const unsigned int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int t, i;
  float result = 0, a, b;

  for (t = 0; t < width / TILE_SIZE; ++t) {
    for (i = 0; i != TILE_SIZE; ++i) {
      a = m1[row*width + t*TILE_SIZE + i];
      b = m2[(t*TILE_SIZE + i)*width + col];
      result += a * b;
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  m3[row*width + col] = result;
}

float *
create_matrix_d(int w, int h) {
  float *m;
  if (cudaMalloc(&m, w * h * sizeof(float)) == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to cudaMalloc.\n");
    return NULL;
    //exit(1);
  }
  return m;
}

void
fill_matrix_h(float *const m, int w, int h, float *const values, int nvalues) {
  int i, j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i != w * h; ++i) {
    m[i] = values[j];
    j = (j + 1) % nvalues;
  }
}

int
main(void) {
    int k;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) !=1 || n<1){
        return 0;
    }
    if (scanf(" %d", &k) !=1 || k<0){
        return 0;
    }
    float *hm[3], *dm[3];
    dim3 bdim(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    dim3 gdim(SIZE/TILE_SIZE, SIZE/TILE_SIZE);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        hm[i] = create_matrix_h(SIZE, SIZE);
        dm[i] = create_matrix_d(SIZE, SIZE);
    }
    float tem[n*n];
    for(i=0; i<n*n; ++i) {
        if (scanf(" %f", &tem[i]) !=1){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    float temid[n*n];
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i != n*n; ++i) {
        if (i==0 || j == n) { // not j + (n+1)
            temid[i] = 1;
            j=0;
        }
        else {
            temid[i] = 0;
            j++;
        }
    }
    fill_matrix_h(hm[0], SIZE, SIZE, tem, sizeof(tem)/sizeof(float));
    fill_matrix_h(hm[1], SIZE, SIZE, temid, sizeof(temid)/sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dm[0], hm[0], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dm[1] = dm[0]; // For the first iteration Result = A * A;
    int w;
    if (k==0) {
        hm[2] = hm[1];
    }
    else if (k==1) {
        hm[2] = hm[0];
    }
    else {
        for (w=1; w<k; ++w) {
           kernel3<<<gdim, bdim>>>(dm[0], dm[1], dm[2], SIZE);
           cudaThreadSynchronize();
           // No need to copy back to host
           // cudaMemcpy(hm[2], dm[2], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
           // Copy between device pointers
           cudaMemcpy(dm[1], dm[2], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice); 
        }
        cudaMemcpy(hm[2], dm[1], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
    }



    print_matrix(hm[2], n, n);

    return 0;

 }
```

Comment: if this is homework or coursework, you should really tag it as such. There are widely differing opinions here about whether homework questions are valid on stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks i'll remember that for the future

Answer (score 1):

I believe we're in the same course here. (comp2129). In response to your infinite loop, your block size/tilesize is too small. Set your block to 16 and try again. I'm getting seg faults though D:.

Comment: haha! yes I think quite a few people are feeling our pain, theres a sea of red on the submission page. Oh well, exam to worry bout now.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the identity matrix wrong.

```
for (i = 0; i != n*n; ++i) {
        if (i==0 || i == j + (n)) { // not j + (n+1)
            temid[i] = 1;
            j = i;
        }
        else {
            temid[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

In fact you do not need to multiply by the identity matrix as you know the result is always going to be the input.

Change this

```
fill_matrix_h(hm[0], SIZE, SIZE, tem, sizeof(tem)/sizeof(float));
fill_matrix_h(hm[1], SIZE, SIZE, temid, sizeof(temid)/sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(dm[0], hm[0], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
int w;
for (w=0; w<k; ++w) {
    cudaMemcpy(dm[1], hm[1], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel3<<<gdim, bdim>>>(dm[0], dm[1], dm[2], SIZE);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(hm[2], dm[2], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    hm[1] = hm[2];
}
```

to

```
fill_matrix_h(hm[0], SIZE, SIZE, tem, sizeof(tem)/sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(dm[0], hm[0], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
dm[1] = dm[0]; // For the first iteration Result = A * A;
int w;
for (w=0; w<k; ++w) {
   kernel3<<<gdim, bdim>>>(dm[0], dm[1], dm[2], SIZE);
   cudaThreadSynchronize();
   // No need to copy back to host
   // cudaMemcpy(hm[2], dm[2], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   // Copy between device pointers
   cudaMemcpy(dm[1], dm[2], SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you comment on what you mean by infinite loop ? As in print the value of W at the beginning of each loop ?

Comment: Hi. Hmm maybe its not a loop, when i run in gdb it just says

"[New Thread 0x7ffff778b700 (LWP 9650)]"
"[New Thread 0x7ffff778a700 (LWP 9651)]"

etc

Comment: until presumabley 64 where it just stops